# Why is init.js using a synchronous XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, chrome

Newer version of the Chrome browser are shouting warnings when the `XMLHttpRequest` object is being used synchronously. We all know that we must not block the main UI thread with unnecessary synchronous calls.

I recently noticed that also one of the core SharePoint JavaScript libraries, `init.js`, is generating such a warning in Chrome!

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Part of the function `UpdateFormDigest` is the following faulty line:

```
b.open("POST", GetUrlFromWebUrlAndWebRelativeUrl(f, "_vti_bin/sites.asmx"), false);
```

Where the `false` parameter states a synchronous request.

Searching on the web was not providing me any evidence that Microsoft is currently working on this particular piece of legacy code.

Anyone in the StackExchange community picked something up?

I have checked this against the following SharePoint versions:

- SharePoint Server 15.0.0.4569
- SharePoint Online 16.0.0.4107

Comment: Hi! Any updates?

Comment: Aha, Ok. It is only warning. I had an issue in defferent place. Ok